# How do you make a field read only using Arcobjects?

Tags: arcobjects, fields-attributes

I have created add-in toolbar with C# arcobjects. I am creating some empty geodatabase shapefiles. While creating featureclass i want to assign some default value to attribute and then make it read-only so user can not modify that value later.

```c#
IField field = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.FieldClass();
IFieldEdit fieldEdit= (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFieldEdit)field ;
fieldEdit.Name_2 = "something"
fieldEdit.Type_2 = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString;
fieldEdit.Length_2 = 10;
fieldEdit.DefaultValue_2 = "yes";
```

when i set `fieldEdit.Editable_2 = false`, then in attribute table, i see default value null instead of "yes", field is non editable.

I want field value as yes and non editable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  Certainly not with shapefiles.  The IFieldEdit [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000347000000) itself states:

> The IFieldEdit interface is used when creating new fields. You should
>   not use it to modify fields, for that purpose use IClassSchemaEdit.

and the Editable property in both IFieldEdit and [IFieldEdit2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFieldEdit2_Interface/002500000348000000/) (which superceded it) both state (emphasis added):

> Editable |    Indicates if the field can be edited. **This should always be set to true.**

Logically, only the objectid column of file geodatabase and the SDE-set rowid columns in enterprise geodatabases could have Editable = false, and even then there's no ArcObjects-supported way to pick and choose on columns on a per-row basis, even in databases which support column-level permission models.  Shapefiles are all strictly O/S permission at the feature class level, and file geodatabase at the workspace level.

Comment: I agree. However how about ObjectID field which is created by default. It has unique value and non-editable?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the interface [IFieldInfo3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ifieldinfo3.htm) it has a property called `ReadOnly`, you can get to this object via the [ITableFields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#itablefields.htm) interface.

As I understand the object model you are getting the `FieldInfo` object from say a `FeatureLayer` and not a `FeatureClass`. So turning `ReadOnly` to True is changing how the field is presented when as a layer object and not the source table (e.g. a geodatabase featureclass).